# Is there a function to cut a multiple the same values on combobox in c#

Tags: c#, combobox

[PIC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymETj.png)
I try to show all the values that are not repeated.

This is for software that will display a meteorological report

```
        private void frm_main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string path = @"C:\Meteo";

        if (Directory.Exists(path))
        {
            listBox1.Items.Clear();
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path);               

            string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(path);

            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                var formattedName = Path.GetFileName(file).Split('_').First();

                //Показва и годината и месеца
                //var formattedName = string.Join("_", Path.GetFileName(file).Split('_').Skip(1).Take(2)); 

                comboBox2.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(formattedName));  

                listBox1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(file));
                //comboBox2.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(formattedName));

            }

            foreach (string dir in dirs)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(path));
            }      
        }

        else

        {
            MessageBox.Show("Директорията Meteo не е октирта в системен диск 'C:\'");
            Application.ExitThread();
        }      
    }
```

I expect only non-repeatable values to appear.
Picture: [values of combobox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwRkS.png)

Comment: What are the filenames you're iterating? The code doesn't show anything like _"only non-repeatable"_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply not add the value if the combobox already contains the value.

Example:

```
string[] someValues = { "one", "two", "two", "three", "four", "four", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten", "ten" };

foreach(string val in someValues)
{
    // Only add the value to combobox if the combobox doesn't already contain it
    if (!comboBox1.Items.Contains(val))
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Add(val);
    }
}
```